# React-Native how give a method an variable

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change a variable in state so I give it to a component as property later on, but i can't seem to change the variable.

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            reading: false,
            iName: 'default'
        };
        this.startRead = this.startRead.bind(this);
    }

    startRead = ({item}) => {
        this.setState({
            reading: true,
            iName: {item.name} //it doesn't work over here
        });
    }

    renderItem = ({item}) => {
        this.setName
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}} onPress={this.startRead}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text> // this does work
                <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
```

I called this renderItem function via a FlatList

```
    this.state.reading ?
    <ReadScreen iname={this.state.iName}/>
    :
    <View style={styles.slide}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
    </View>
```

It gives me an error of
"SyntaxError: App.js: Unexpected token, expected ',' (21,24)"

(21,24) gives the line

> iName: {item.name}

What am I doing wrong?

The goal is; when I press a Item of the FlatList, a.k.a. the `TouchableOpacity`, it renders the ReadScreen that shows, more given information through properties instead of the FlatList.

If it's unclear or need more information, just ask

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
onPress={this.startRead}
```

With this line

```
onPress={() => this.startRead({item})}
```

Here's the full solution

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    this.setName
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}} onPress={() => this.startRead({item})}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text> // this does work
            <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm new to this and I couldn't find the answer nor describe this problem very well

Comment: You need to pass the object to the method, not doing that you will pass the event from onPress

Answer (score 0):

Use `iName: item.name` instead of `iName:{item.name}`

Comment: When i use "iName: item.name" it gives an error of "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name')